# How to integrate Google GSI with Kotlin/JS

Tags: kotlin, google-signin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

Am trying to implement Google on-tap sign-in in a Kotlin/Js project.

Is there any kotlin-wrapper like library available to use https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client in a Kotlin/Js project?

Or is there any reference on how this can be done?

I tried this -

In my index.html, as per gsi docs

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

And in kotlin/Js react app

```
val google: dynamic = window.asDynamic().google

val SignIn =
    FC<Props> {    
        useEffect {      
            google.accounts.id.initialize()
    }
 }
```

But I get this error on browser

**Unexpected Application Error!**

**Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'accounts')**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you immediately trying to access `window.google`, when google client script hasn't been loaded. `async` and `defer` attributes ensure that script will be loaded asynchroniusly after document has been parsed. So when this line

```kotlin
val google: dynamic = window.asDynamic().google
```

is executing, it is always `null`.

I suggest you change it to this line:

```
val google: dynamic get() = window.asDynamic().google
```

In that case you will access `window.google` on demand.